# Can I convert a shape into a button within VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to convert shapes that are already in the sheet into buttons. I've searched, but all i can find are how to add macros to buttons from within excel itself, and not via VBA.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can use OnAction

```
Sub gen_button()
    l = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Left
    t = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Top
    w = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Width
    h = ActiveSheet.Range("H10:H11").Height

    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, l, t, w, h)
    shp.OnAction = "Shape_Click"
    shp.Select

    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Selection.Text = "Generaty"
    Selection.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    Selection.HorizontalAlignment = 1
    Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)


End Sub
```